# Javascript to check data format is nor working properly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a validation to check the date format using javascript. But I still have the error message the date format is not valid even when I enter the right date format
I don't know if my regular expression is right I found it on the net

Thanks for your help

```
function CheckDateFormat()
{
    var StartDateform= document.getElementById('tblTarget').rows[1].cells[StartDate].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    var pattern;

    // Regular expression used to check if date is in correct format
    pattern= new RegExp("^([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})$");

    if(StartDateform.match(pattern))
    {
        var date_array;
        var day;
        date_array = StartDateform.value.split('-');
        day = date_array[0];

        // Attention! Javascript consider months in the range 0 - 11

        var month; 
        var year; 

        month= date_array[1] - 1;
        year= date_array[2];

        // This instruction will create a date object
        //source_date = new Date(year,month,day);

        source_date = new Date(day,month,year);

        if(year != source_date.getFullYear())
        {
            alert('Year is not valid!');
            return false;
        }

        if(month != source_date.getMonth())
        {
            alert('Month is not valid!');
            return false;
        }

        if(day != source_date.getDate())
        {
            alert('Day is not valid!');
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Date format is not valid!');
        InvalidFlag=1;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Well first off, what date format do you believe you should be submitting, and what format are you actually submitting? Second, you can use `console.log();` in javascript combined with either firefox or chrome's developer console to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) that will handle date parsing and validation for you.  It will be more flexible than your regex and can accept various formats.

If you want to stick with the regular expression, [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) is a good site to test JavaScript regex.  It looks like your regex successfully matches dates of the format `dd-mm-yyyy`.  What was your test date that didn't work?  Because the `^` and `$` characters match the start and end of a string, your date can't have any extra spaces.  E.g:

`"05-07-1998"` will match the regex.

`"05-07-1998 "` will not match it.

Edit:

If you're trying to get dates in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, you need to either use `Moment.js` or change your regex to be: `^([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})$`.

Because you're using `/` to delimit your dates instead of `-`, this line will need to be also need to be changed:

```
date_array = StartDateform.value.split('/'); // must split on '/' instead of '-'
```

Comment: Sorry Guys I am trying to get a format dd/mm/yyyy I tested the code with the data 15/07/2013 that did not work. I sorry I am more a database person so I am new with javascript